# Magneto 2.4.1 Collection: __construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface

Tags: magento2, collection

I have a custom module with a few tables. I have the model, resource model and collection classes in place. If I try to access the contents of the table, I am getting this error

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\ModuleModel\ResourceModel\AddressGroups\Collection\Interceptor, Argument 5 passed to Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AddressGroups\Collection\Interceptor::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface or be null, string given, called in /home/user/magentoTest/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

I'm getting this error only in production mode. If I switch to developer mode, everything seems to be working fine.

This is my collection.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AddressGroups;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection{

    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\AddressGroups', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AddressGroups');
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your Collection.php file

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a virtual type with the namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AddressGroups\Collection which already exists.

As a result, AbstractFactory will pass the arguments (mainTable and resourceModel) to the __construct function of AbstractCollection instead of SearchResult, which throws an exception because AbstractCollection does not accept the arguments as a string whereas SearchResult does.

To solve the problem, you have to rename the virtual type namespace to Vendor\Module\Model\Resourc
eModel\AddressGroups\Grid\Collection

See the code below:

```
    <virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AddressGroups\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">address_groups</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AddressGroups</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="addressGroups_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AddressGroups\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Flush cache with php bin/magento c:f and compile the code bin/magento setup:di:compile. It should work now.

Comment: It took a long time to understand your solution and the problem with 'already existing'. I renamed the name of the virtual item by inserting "VirtualType". So Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\MyTemplate\VirtualType\Collection instead of Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\MyTemplate\Collection in etc/di.xml of the module.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, to be sure you are passing the right args into the function in your file, dont directly enter classnames as strings. Do this, as it is best practice.

Also, the visibility on `_construct` should be protected. You have public.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AddressGroups;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct(){
        $this->_init(\Vendor\Module\Model\AddressGroups::class, \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\AddressGroups::class);
    }
}
```

Beyond that, delete the generated/code/Vendor/Module directory. Sometimes, when you update a class's constructor or anything that affects the Interceptor class, you might need to delete filed from generated/code.

The error you posted makes it sound like you had a constructor in your class and possibly you removed it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I never had a constructor in this class

Comment: @coderGeek Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too. I'm pretty sure I've discovered why!

In my UpgradeSchema.php I did not have:
'''
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
'''
but I was calling the AdapterInterface while adding an index near the end of the upgrade() function.

I too had switched modes from developer to production, but I think it's because when I uploaded to the server and got some other errors, the UpgradeSchema was being used whereas it was not being tested on my development machine. That or my local setup is more lenient. I should say I'm on 2.3.7 for dev machine and 2.4.2 on production server.

In the end, I should have wiped out the database table on my dev machine and tested the UpgradeSchema, and it probably would have shown the error.

BTW: The way I discovered the problem was I'm reusing those classes, and when I was comparing them, I noticed the "use" statement was only at the top of the InstallSchema.php, and those files (in my case) should be virtually identical.

Answer (score 0):

If it can help, I resolve the same issue by adding **_construct()** method in my Model class. It was missing.